# Moderator/high rep abuse?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I'm not sure of this belongs on parenting meta, or SO meta... so I'll leave it here until otherwise suggested.

An original comment from a member with 30,000+ on SO in response an my answer on [Teenagers and Internet Access](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/32712/teenagers-and-internet-access) was a rather snarky opinion about my definition of 'privacy' as laughable; which seemed a little trollish.

What followed was a brief and minor back-and-forth whereby the high rep member then used their rep on SO to defend their position -- *which I respectfully deflected because*, while they have a very high SO rep, it quickly became clear they didn't understand privacy in the sense of information security and didn't grasp infosec very well based on their contributions, comments, and answers on the infosec Q&A. InfoSec is actually what I do professionally, though I don't claim to be a guru or anything, and where I derive my position on and definition of privacy in the context of my answer. (One of my comments illustrated the difference between legal privacy, and actual privacy.)

I thought (most) my comments well articulated, polite, and defended. I came back today to find ***ALL*** my responses deleted, and the high rep member's comment edited to be less of a personal attack (thanks) on my position, but still missing my point and attempting to make me look foolish.

If the member wanted to edit their comment, fine, but why delete my reasonable responses? To remove my on-point responses (Granted, not all were.) seems like significant abuse.

**What to do?** From my position this looks like abuse.

Comment: I can state that it wouldn't have been intentional abuse, at worst overzealous trimming; as I am not the moderator that performed either action, I've pinged the one who did so you can get a response :)

Comment: thanks @Erica :)

Comment: @NonCreature0714 - my apologies; this was certainly not done to make you appear foolish. There was an argument, which a user flagged,  asking to have it removed (which I did.) Comments are supposed to clarify or recommend improvement to the answer; I thought that removing the insulting language was enough, as (what do I know?) I thought the rest was accurate. But I will (as we discussed) undelete your longer response.

Comment: I wanted to let you know that I moved the comment thread to a chat room. You were quick to use the word "abuse", but continued being argumentative in comments. Comments is neither the place to insult others, impugn their motives, or establish your credentials. This goes for everyone.

Comment: @anongoodnurse thanks, that’s certainly the better choice. The comment thread went certainly went out of hand and off topic, and attracted comments for longer than I expected; even this several month old meta.